# Changing the text once clicked and preventing it to revert back to original text once the page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that changes the text into something else once it's clicked. It's working fine and changes when clicked but once the page is refreshed, the text reverts back to the original text.

```
$('a.like-link').text('Unlike');
```

That's what I'm using by the way.

Is there any way to prevent the text from reverting back to the original text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to persist the new state somehow. You could use an AJAX request to update a database, or set a cookie, for example.

Comment: Would that mean if the cookies are cleared, then the text would revert back to the orignal?

Comment: Yes. Maintaining state on the server is the only permanent solution. But that means user authentication and everything that goes with it, like passwords :)

Comment: Oh ok! that made sense. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Two options;

1. Doing it server side
   Useful links:

   - Sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
   - MySQL: http://au.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php (would be combined with an AJAX request, most likely)
2. Doing it with cookies
   Useful links:

   - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: So there are no way to do it with jquery?

Comment: jQuery is a library in javascript; why not just copy the example? However, http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/